# Vim pdf viewer blocking the terminal

Tags: vim

When I call the command `command ViewPdf !okular %:r.pdf`  on Vim (in .vimrc), the terminal is blocked and I cannot continue writing my document.How can i tweake this vim command to open my pdfviewer and let me write the text in vim? I tried this options already:

```
command ViewPdf !okular %:r.pdf &
command ViewPdf !okular %:r.pdf & disown
command ViewPdf !okular %:r.pdf && disown
```

**[Edit-1]:** I don't want to use plugins to do this. I have a pretty sh** machine so I want to avoid adding things to my runtime, if possible

**[Edit-2]:**  my .vimrc file:

```
   command ViewPdf execute "!okular %:r.pdf &" | redraw  
   command CompileXelatex !xelatex  -interaction=nonstopmode %
   command CompileLatex !latexmk -pdfxe %
```

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to let the reader fork into the background silently and redraw in VIM:

```
:command ViewPdf execute "silent !okular %:r.pdf&" | redraw!
```

This uses `execute` so that only the things in the quotes after the exclamation mark are passed to the shell and the `| redraw!` is interpreted by VIM.

The `redraw` might not always be necessary (I'm actually not sure when it really is), so instead just

```
:command ViewPdf silent !okular %:r.pdf&
```

might work as well.

Alternatively, you could as well solve this with a mapping, e.g.,

```
:nmap <leader>s :silent ! okular %:r.pdf&<cr> :redraw!<cr>
```

This will define the key combination `<leader>s` to open okular for you in normal mode. `<leader>` uses the key which is stored in `mapleader` (by default a backslash, you can use `:let mapleader = ","` to make it a comma instead for example).

Comment: It didn't work. The pdfviewer doesn't open

Comment: @LATEXNOOBJP did you execute that command as is in VIM normal mode, or did you put that into your vimrc? If the latter, did you remove the leading colon and resource the file?

Comment: I arealdy tested the option without the redraw, it locks the terminal and i cant type anything after

Comment: about the commet, my case is the latter. I did as you said: remove the leading colon since is not needed when defining a command in the .vimrc

Comment: @LATEXNOOBJP for me this is certainly working (only difference is that I use another PDF-viewer as I don't have okular installed). What's the output of using `:command ViewPdf` in normal mode?

Comment: The option without `redraw!` was missing the trailing `&`.

Comment: I just tested and it works with `okular` as well on my machine.

Comment: The output of `:command ViewPdf` is 

`ViewPdf     0                                  !okular %:r.pdf& <Space> `

Comment: @LATEXNOOBJP looks like you didn't resource your vimrc. Can you put the first code block of my answer in your vimrc and restart the vim instance in which you're trying to open your pdf? Alternatively, use the version with the leading colon in normal mode of your vim and add a `!` after `command` to overwrite the command.

Comment: OK, I'll try. One minute

Comment: So, after I did it, the command is registered as `ViewPdf     0                                  execute "silent !okular %:r.pdf&" | redraw!` but when I try to use it,is the same thing: Calls, gives no errors and doesn't open the viewer

Comment: That is strange. Are you sure the pdf exists? Which version of VIM are you running? Maybe ask a new question over at https://vi.stackexchange.com/ where there are more experienced users of VIM over there.

Comment: I'm sure that the pdf exists. Executing a ls in the directory that I'm in show me the pdf I want to open. I'm really grateful for trying to solve my problem. Thank you for your time, I'm going to ask on vi.exchange.com